# how to change the object tab colour

Tags: visualforce

how to change the object tab colour of opportunity to account tab colour to match the related list of account

`<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="controller" tabstyle="Opportunity">
<apex:form >
<apex:sectionheader title="Subscriptions" />`

to make whole account detail record page look like one style rather than in different style

Answer (score 2):

http://teachmesalesforce.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/changing-tab-logo-using-styling/

Was looking at this blog and it says you can create your own style and own image and use the same .

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Change-the-color-of-Standard-Tabs/td-p/277299

```
<style>
.accountTab .tabNavigation .tab .currentTab, .accountTab #contentWrapper #motifCurve,    .accountTab #contentWrapper #motifCurve div {
background-color: #f00;
 }
</style>
```

This was technique used .That is by using inspect element you can overide the CSS .Observing the CSS in chrome inspect element may help.

Answer (score 1):

try using tabstyle="account" that should pull all colors related to the account tab.

Updated again with setup attribute:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account"  tabstyle="Opportunity" extensions="controller" setup="true">
 <apex:form > 
 <apex:sectionheader title="Subscriptions" />
 <apex:pageblock tabstyle="account" title="Account Style">
 <apex:inputfield value="{!account.name}"/>
 </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: If i use tabstyle ="account" i dont get the opportunity image to that, so i am looking for account style with opportunity image

Comment: check the setup ="true"