# VF tabstyle highlights to the primary object

Tags: visualforce, tab, object

So I have a Visual force tab named **Order Tracking** that overrides the default recent view of the **Order** object records in the following way:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Order_Tracking__tab">
  <script type="text/javascript" tabStyle="Order_Tracking__tab">
      parent.frames.location.replace("/009?fcf=00cxxx0");
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

So when I click it displays the required list view. But the problem I'm facing is that when I click the **Order Tracking** tab the **Order** tab gets selected instead. So I add tabstyle to the vf page. But it still goes back to highlight the **order** tab.

What should I do to highlight **Order Tracking** visualforce tab when I click on it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post the apex:page tag of your Visualforce page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the object tab colour](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/how-to-change-the-object-tab-colour)

Comment: @ChristianDeckert You got me wrong. I don't want to use styling. Just want to default the tab highlights.

Comment: Could you explain what iframes are in play here?

Comment: yes, its a custom list view for order object

Comment: First it highlights Order Tracking tab, then finally highlights back to Order tab on complete loading the list view.

Comment: I'm still unable to find an answer. Since it's an observation only from my end, I decided to share with the community!